# Adobe Sign API: "access_denied: Scopes not enabled for this application" while creating OAUTH access token

Tags: adobe, echosign, adobe-sign

I want to create an access token for the "Acrobat Sign REST API V6".
I'm logged into the echosign backend `https://newsign.eu1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/`

Now I try to create the access token. I click on the "baseUris" section and then on the "OAUTH ACCESS-TOKEN" button.

Then I enable **every** of the scopes and then I click on the button "Authorize". I get the following error message:

```
access_denied: Scopes not enabled for this application
```

Answer (score 0):

I read that "baseUris" is only available to enterprise accounts (or it may be a bug). You can do the following work around to get an access token to use for baseUris.

To walk those not familiar with the over all process on getting a temporary token for testing APIs:

1. Log in to your echo sign account: https://secure.echosign.com/public/login
2. Click on "API" on the top menu
3. Click on/Expand the Acrobat Sign API on the left hand menu
4. Click on API Information, if you aren't already there
5. On the main screen click on "REST API Methods Documentation".
6. It isn't obvious but scrolling down to "Resources and Operations", here you can test APIs.
7. For transientDocuments click on "Expand Operations"
8. So here you can click on the "OAUTH ACCESS-TOKEN" button to generate a temporary token to use in postman or your own test (depending on scope).
9. You can look at the other resources to find the correct scope if transient documents doesn't contain the correct scope.
10. If you have gone through the transient workflow then now you have a access token. You can copy that access token to the BaseUris and use it there.